# How to get value of variable entered from user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a basic menu that checks to see if the variable entered matches a defined variable. If the variable is defined get the data of the defined variable.

Example.

```
Item1 = "bill"
Item2 = "cows"
item3 = "abcdef"
Choose_Item = input("Select your item: ")
```

- I type in `Item1`
- `Choose_Item` should equal `"bill"`

Comment: And what have you tried? This seems more like a code request than a question.

Comment: ``Choose_Item = globals()[input("Select your item: ")]``

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This seems like what you're looking for:

```
Choose_Item = eval(input("Select your item:  "))
```

This probably isn't the best strategy, though, because a typo or a malicious user can easily crash your code, overload your system, or do any other kind of nasty stuff they like. For this particular case, a better approach might be

```
items = {'item1': 'bill', 'item2': 'cows', 'item3': 'abcdef'}
choice = input("Select your item: ")
if choice in items:
    the_choice = items[choice]
else:
    print("Uh oh, I don't know about that item")
```

Comment: Bah you beat me to the punch with literally the same advice. +1 for the faster typer ;)

Comment: I was just typing a similar comment on your answer, so you won that race at least. :)

Comment: [Oof, I see `eval` on user input...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 4):

Two ways you could go about this. The bad way:

```
print(eval(Choose_Item))
```

The better way would be to use a dictionary

```
items = {'1':'bill','2':'cows'}
Choose_Item = input("Select your Item: ")
try:
    print(items[Choose_Item])
except KeyError:
    print('Item %s not found' % Choose_Item)
```

Comment: FWIW: question is tagged python-3, so you'd want parens in that print statement, and you probably also want to print something in the exception case rather than just building a string and not doing anything with it. :)

Comment: But aren't random strings good programming etiquette? Good catch sir, another reason why you deserve this answer

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use `locals()[Choose_Item]` if you want to choose a variable whose name is what the user produced.

A more conventional way to do this, though, is to use a dictionary:

```
items = {
    'Item1': 'bill',
    'Item2': 'cows',
    'Item3': 'abcdef',
}
```

... and then the value you want is `items[Choose_Item]`.

Comment: +1 - the locals approach is better than eval, in that it at least doesn't let a malicious user go and, well, evaluate code. :)  Of course the dictionary approach is preferable.