# Python use input to select local variable inside another function

Tags: python, global-variables, local-variables

All, I have this request but first I will explain what I'm trying to achieve. I coded a python script with many global variables but also many methods defined inside different modules (.py files).

The script sometimes moves to a method and inside this method I call another method defined in another module. The script is quite complex.

Most of my code is inside Try/Except so that every time an exception is triggered my code runs a method called "check_issue()" in which I print to console the traceback and then I ask myself if there's any variable's value I want to double check. Now, I read many stackoverflow useful pages in which users show how to use/select globals(), locals() and eval() to see current global variables and local variables.

What I would specifically need though is the ability to input inside method "check_issue()" the name of a variable that may be defined not as global and not inside the method check_issue() either.
Using classes is not a solution since I would need to change hundreds of lines of code.

These are the links I already read:

- [Viewing all defined variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633127/viewing-all-defined-variables)
- [Calling variable defined inside one function from another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139866/calling-variable-defined-inside-one-function-from-another-function)
- [How to get value of variable entered from user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168765/how-to-get-value-of-variable-entered-from-user-input)

This is a sample code that doesn't work:

```
a =  4
b = "apple"

def func_a():
    c = "orange"
    ...
    check_issue()

def check_issue():
    print("Something went wrong")
    var_to_review = input("Input name of var you want to review")
    # I need to be able to enter "c" and print the its value "orange"
    print(func_a.locals()[var_to_review ]) # this doesn't work
```

Could somebody suggest how to fix it?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you call `locals()` inside `check_issue()`, you can only access to the locals of this function, which would be : `['var_to_review']`.

You can add a parameter to the check_issue function and pass locals whenever you call it.

```
a =  4
b = "apple"

def func_a():
    c = "orange"
    check_issue(locals())

def check_issue(local_vars):
    print("Something went wrong")
    var_to_review = input("Input name of var you want to review")
    print(local_vars[var_to_review])
```

Comment: This is a first great step and I would want to thank you for the prompt answer. There's a problem though. The code above is a simplistic representation of the real script I have. Meaning, I could call check_issue() inside method func_a() and func_a() may have been called inside func_b() and func_b() may be coming from another method called func_c(). What would you suggest in that case? How could I check local variables inside func_a(), func_b() and func_c() from check_issue() ? Thanks