# how can I specify an input as the python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

User enters an input like this: 4*3**2
Is there anyway to perform this, as a python code (not string)?
I mean something like this:

```
x = input('Enter a operation: ') # 4*3**2
print('Answer is:', x) # expect: 'Answer is: 36'
```

Comment: How long evaluated code supposed to be?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168765/how-to-get-value-of-variable-entered-from-user-input

Answer (score 3):

You could use `eval`:

```
x = input('Enter a operation: ')
print('Answer is:', eval(x))
```

But the problem is that `eval` is unsafe and inefficient, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) for more information.

Comment: Hmm. But if someone could see ```eval()``` it could turn out to be really dangerous

Comment: @Sujay I mentioned that under

Comment: its insecure, because user can enter other thing and reveal my code, (is it correct?) so what if I use if statement to limit user and let him just use some special characters, like 1-9 and * and / and + and - ....?